# SQL - Query to find unique SSN and DOB values from a table for UUID column

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say there are 2 tables.

Table 1 : match 
Table 2 : normalized

In table1 there is a column uuid and in table2 there are columns uuid, SSN and DOB. After joining these two tables, i need to fetch the records only having the unique SSN and DOB for the uuid

Scenario : Find all the uuid that have unique SSN and DOB

I have tried with the below query:

```
SELECT x.UUID, x.SSN, x.DOB
FROM TABLE_NAME AS x
  JOIN (
    SELECT UUID
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY UUID
    HAVING COUNT(UUID ) = 1
  ) AS y
  ON x.UUID = y.UUID
```

I'm not getting the correct output. Can anyone please help me with the query.

Output Example:

| Record # | uuid | ssn | dob | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456789 | 54321 | 03/08/1986 | SSN is repeated in record #3 |
| 2 | 123456789 | 98765 | 03/08/1986 | DOB is repeated in record #1 |
| 3 | 123456789 | 54321 | 03/08/1986 | SSN is repeated in record #1 |
| 4 | 123456789 | 77654 | 10/10/2000 | SSN is repeated in record #5 |
| 5 | 998764556 | 77654 | 11/11/1960 | SSN is repeated in record #4 |
| 6 | 112233445 | 66546 | 07/14/1970 | SSN and DOB is unique |

Answer (score 0):

You do not need subquery with the same table for this. The task can be solved by simple analytic function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41): include the columns of interest into the `PARTITION BY` and select only first row per group:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     trunc(level / 15) as uuid,
>     sysdate + trunc(level / 3) as dob,
>     decode(mod(level, 2), 0, 'AA', dbms_random.string('x', 4)) as ssn
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 30
> )
> , unique_ as (
>   select a.*
>     , row_number()
>         over(
>           partition by uuid, ssn, dob
>           order by 1
>         ) as rn
>   from a
> )
> select *
> from unique_
> where rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> UUID | DOB       | SSN  | RN
> ---: | :-------- | :--- | -:
>    0 | 15-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    0 | 16-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    0 | 17-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    0 | 18-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    0 | 19-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    0 | 16-APR-21 | BGZC |  1
>    0 | 18-APR-21 | E2Z7 |  1
>    0 | 17-APR-21 | E6TE |  1
>    0 | 19-APR-21 | JF33 |  1
>    0 | 16-APR-21 | NKJV |  1
>    0 | 15-APR-21 | X5R6 |  1
>    0 | 18-APR-21 | XDH7 |  1
>    1 | 21-APR-21 | 054I |  1
>    1 | 22-APR-21 | 2FK3 |  1
>    1 | 22-APR-21 | 66G0 |  1
>    1 | 20-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    1 | 21-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    1 | 22-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    1 | 23-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    1 | 24-APR-21 | AA   |  1
>    1 | 20-APR-21 | B4R6 |  1
>    1 | 23-APR-21 | CV33 |  1
>    1 | 24-APR-21 | LV9Y |  1
>    1 | 24-APR-21 | U1DG |  1
>    1 | 20-APR-21 | YO12 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2d3cb4384a49c1513485e2e7ceec86a)*

Comment: Thanks for the response, Could you please elaborate the explanation i couldn't understand completely, little help required as i'm new to SQL platform. My Actual Requirement is, First i need to join the tables(match and normalized) based on uuid column and need to fetch common uuid's after that i need to filter the uuid's by unique SSN and DOB.

Comment: @SuryaKrishna I calculate row number per each UUID, SSN and DOB and then select only first record per group. If you need only one SSN and DOB per UUID, then remove that two columns from `partition by` part of query.

Answer (score 0):

> Find all the uuid that have unique SSN and DOB

Just use aggregation:

```
select uuid, min(ssn) as ssn, min(dob) as dob
from table_name
group by uuid
having count(distinct ssn) = 1 and
       count(distinct dob) = 1;
```

I sometimes find that comparing min and max values is a wee bit faster:

```
select uuid, min(ssn) as ssn, min(dob) as dob
from table_name
group by uuid
having min(ssn) = max(ssn) and
       min(dob) = max(dob);
```

But it depends on the nature of the data.